# 400 ошибка в Телеграм Чат Бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Ребята, подскажите: возникает ошибка в чат боте при отправке документа. По факту, документ отправлен, но в консоли при каждой очередной отправке ошибка. Библиотека `telebot`.

Фрагмент кода на отправку:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def inline(c):

# Завление в папки Прочее
if c.data == 'other':
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=c.message.chat.id,
                          message_id=c.message.message_id,
                          text=kb.OTHER,
                          reply_markup=kb.keyboard_other)
elif c.data == 'APPLICATION_FOR_EMPLOYMENT':
    chat_id = c.message.chat.id
    message_id = c.message.message_id
    bot.send_document(chat_id, dir.application_for_employment(kb.APPLICATION_FOR_EMPLOYMENT))
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=chat_id,
                          message_id=message_id,
                          text=kb.OTHER,
                          reply_markup=kb.keyboard_other)
```

> 2020-05-27 17:57:16,946 (util.py:68 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot:
> "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was
> unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response
> body:\n[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request:
> message is not modified: specified new message content and reply
> markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of
> the message"}']',) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Valeria\Desktop\aio_pytelegrambot\evn\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py",
> line 62, in run
> task(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:/Users/Valeria/Desktop/aio_pytelegrambot/main.py", line 30, in
> inline
> reply_markup=kb.keyboard_other)   File "C:\Users\Valeria\Desktop\aio_pytelegrambot\evn\lib\site-packages\telebot_*init*_.py",
> line 1090, in edit_message_text
> disable_web_page_preview, reply_markup)   File "C:\Users\Valeria\Desktop\aio_pytelegrambot\evn\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py",
> line 682, in edit_message_text
> return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')   File
> "C:\Users\Valeria\Desktop\aio_pytelegrambot\evn\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py",
> line 65, in _make_request
> return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']   File "C:\Users\Valeria\Desktop\aio_pytelegrambot\evn\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py",
> line 84, in _check_result
> raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result) telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was
> unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
> [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message is
> not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are
> exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the
> message"}'] " 2020-05-27 17:57:16,946 (**init**.py:443 MainThread)
> ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The
> server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
> [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message is
> not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are
> exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the
> message"}']"

Answer (score 3):

Зачем вы изменяете сообщение после отправки документа?
В консоли даже написано `Bad Request: message is not modified`

Замените

```
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=chat_id,
                          message_id=message_id,
                          text=kb.OTHER,
                          reply_markup=kb.keyboard_other)
```

на

```
bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, '{}'.format(kb.OTHER), reply_markup=kb.keyboard_other)
```